# Canceling the transaction

Tags: stellar-sdk

I am new to stellar transaction. I have created the transaction for 10 XLM from A to B. Now I want to do cancel or approve from client side. for approve, working. for cancel, i don't have idea. how to cancel the transaction in backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of a block chain is that you cannot ever cancel the transaction after you submit it. So if you have submitted it to stellar, it's too late.

Solution: don't do that until after the user approves the transaction, which should include signing the transaction object you are creating client side. If they don't, do not submit that client side object. It does not exist in stellar until you do. There's nothing to remove/cancel from stellar because it was never there.

Comment: can we add timing for particular multisig transaction while creation? like it's valid upto 10 mins or 30 mins or 24 hrs

Comment: yes, just like with a normal transaction you can set timings when you create the object before you send it.

Comment: can you share sample syntax to add timings in transaction in normal transaction?